# understanding how queues(celery etc.) work?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, resque, amazon-sqs

I have been reading a lot about queues and have confused myself. I will just jot down what I know, please let me know, if I understand things correctly.

A queue basically helps you to do things out of the request-response cycle. Meaning, if a client uploads an image, and you want to save the thumbnail version of the image, you do not want to keep the client waiting for the time till the image gets trimmed, and then return him, you do it out of the request-response cycle, via a queue. Queue is almost like the traditional data-structure queue, first in first out sort of.

The popular solution providers for these queues are [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), [pyres](https://github.com/binarydud/pyres), & amazon sqs.

### How does a queue work?

Generally there is a daemon running, for instance, if there is celery then there is a celery daemon which runs, and keeps doing the computation on whichever task is at the top of the queue. (hope i am right on this)

Another example, slightly complicated, please correct me on this.

Now say I want to automate the following task:

1. Send a mail to a friend of mine, on 25th Dec.
2. Wish a friend on her birthday on 26th Dec.
3. Wish another friend on her birthday on 26th Dec.

In this case, what I will do the following:

1. create an entry,  and  in the database.
2. once the entry is created, queue that entry.
3. Fire a worker, which will execute that task.

Now here is the doubt, is step 3 correct?

Is there a long polling worker, which will act?
How does this work? I am confused. Or do I need to have a cron job, running, which will keep firing a script
to check if there is anything in the queue, for the given time(with the precision of minutes) if yes, then fire a worker.

When you look at the documentation of celery, they need a backend - redis, mongodb, sqs etc. So if I am right, there would be a continuous process which will run as a daemon, and will keep a track of things in the queue(redis, mongodb) and should execute. This is the gray area. Please help.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways for using Celery. Let's suppose you're using Celery+Rabbitmq

1. Executing long running tasks ( > you do not want to keep the client waiting for the time till work will be done.)
   You can run celery task from you code executing in web request. It means that your task will serialized to message and will be sent to queue at rabbit server. 
   Other process ( Celery process ), have a consumer which will initialized when message comes to queue. Celery worker get this messages, deserialize it, and execute your task in other thread. That's all.
2. You can start your Celery jobs by cron ( it just changes the sender who  creates a task for Celery, but all other things are same)

p.s. If your are using not RabbitMq, something like Database, Memcached as Broker. Celery will make reads each N seconds, or milliseconds. etc.